# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file

Tags: r

I am very new to R and hoping that someone can help me out. I run this code and I keep getting the cannot open the connection error. I set the directory to the folder I saved the data in and even checked with `file.existis("file_Path/filename")` and I got `True`. Yet, I still get this error. Please help me! Here is the first part of the Code:

```
    daphnia=function(dr="c")
    {
    da=read.csv(paste(dr,":Data_Path/filename",sep=""))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error means that the filepath is incorrect. Can you print out the entire path, i.e. `print(paste(dr,":Data_Path/filename",sep="")`? Sometimes there is an issue of using `\` instead of `/` as well. Is it possible you need `C:/Data_Path/filename`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is the whole path : da=read.csv(paste(dr,"C:/Users/.../R/filename.csv",sep="")). I used / and not \. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Newbee If your path starts with `C:/`, then it's not clear what you would be `paste()`-ing in front of it. If you added another "c" then the path would be incorrect. What exactly did your `file.exists()` code look like? Did you also `paste()` there?

Comment: @MrFlick my file.exists() code didn't have the paste! file.exists("C:/Users/.../filename.csv"). Should I delete the paste from the da=read.csv(paste(dr,"C:/Users/.../filename.csv",sep="")) and run it s da=read.csv(dr,"C:/Users/.../R/filename.csv",sep="")?

Comment: @Newbee if you are not using the `dr` and `paste()` in the `file.exists`, then don't use it in the file path: `read.csv("C:/Users/.../filename.csv")`, You just need to supply a complete, correct file path to the `read.csv` function.